# Фрагмент с ListView для NavigationDrawerActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Как реализовать класс и разметку фрагмента с `ListView` (где и как получить `ListView`), если класс должен наследоваться от `Fragment`?

Такой фрагмент требуется для вставки в контейнер (не в шторку) от `NavigationDrawerActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте класс, расширяющий Fragment
2. Создайте в xml разметку с ListView в ней.
3. В onCreateView класса из п.1 загрузите эту разметку во фрагмент.
4. Отобразите фрагмент.

Для всего этого есть множество туториалов.